# Yii - How to Hide/View Button in CGridview Based on User's Level?

Tags: php, yii

I tried to view or show button (CButtonColumn) in CGridView, in my /views/file/admin.php:

```
....
//getLevel()==1 means ADMIN, getLevel==2 means common users
array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{view}{update}{delete}', 'visible'=> (Yii::app()->user->getLevel()==1),
            'deleteConfirmation'=>"js: 'Are you want to delete '+$(this).parent().parent().children(':first-child').text()+ '?'",

  //I tried to modify with this code below, but there's nothing happens, 'view' button not
  //display when I access as common user (getLevel()==2)    
            'buttons'=>array(
                'view' => array(
                    'visible'=> Yii::app()->user->getLevel()==2,
                ),

            )
    ),
....
```

WebUser.php

```
<?php
class WebUser extends CWebUser{

protected $_model;

protected function loadUser()
{
    if ( $this->_model === null ) {
            $this->_model = User::model()->findByPk($this->id);
    }
    return $this->_model;
}

function getLevel()
{
    $user=$this->loadUser();
    if($user)
        return $user->id_level;
    return 100;
}
}
?>
```

I tried to do that code, but there 'view' button not display, and there's no error when I load the page. Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: try to put this statement in commas 'Yii::app()->user->getLevel()==2'. then see if it works

Comment: I have tried it, but it throws error `call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given`

Comment: ok are you sure that getLevel() returns correct result?

Comment: I think yes, I put method getLevel in WebUser.php that's extends CWebUSer class in Yii. I have updated WebUser.php above in my question. I use `Yii::app()->user->getLevel()` to filter access rules too, and so far so good until I have that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already setting the column visibility to admin users only on the line

```
'template'=>'{view}{update}{delete}', 'visible'=> (Yii::app()->user->getLevel()==1),
```

so

```
    'view' => array(
        'visible'=> Yii::app()->user->getLevel()==2,
    ),
```

has no effect. Remove the first setting for `visible`. Also as @soju and @Rafay said `visible` should be a php expression therefore it should read

```
    'view' => array(
        'visible'=> 'Yii::app()->user->getLevel()==2',
    ),
```

Comment: +1, but `visible` option should be a PHP expression. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn#buttons-detail

Comment: I have tried it, but it throws error `call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given`

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to extend `bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn`.

```
Yii::import('zii.widgets.grid.CButtonColumn');

class EButtonColumnWithRightsCheck extends CButtonColumn{

    public function init() {
        //{view} {delete} {update}
        $permissions = array();
        // Client.User.View
        $permissions['view'] = Yii::app()->user->checkAccess(ucfirst($this->grid->controller->module->id) . '.' . ucfirst($this->grid->controller->id) . '.View');
        $permissions['delete'] = Yii::app()->user->checkAccess(ucfirst($this->grid->controller->module->id) . '.' . ucfirst($this->grid->controller->id) . '.Delete');
        $permissions['update'] = Yii::app()->user->checkAccess(ucfirst($this->grid->controller->module->id) . '.' . ucfirst($this->grid->controller->id) . '.Update');

        foreach ($permissions as $action => $permission) {
            if ($permission === false) {
                $this->template = str_replace('{' . $action . '}', '', $this->template);
            }
        }

        // call parent to initialize other buttons
        parent::init();
    }

}
```